# Trying to make a program, but struggling with delete option

Tags: java, file

if I choose option 3 on this program, I would like it to delete one of the exam grades.

The program outputs like this at the moment if option 2 (view grades) is chosen:

```
1) Bob Jones, Comp, 18
2) Matt Jones, computing, 100
3) Adam Frank-Jones, Drama, 69
```

As you can see in the code, the numbers incrementing down the side are represented by "i". What I'm looking for is if I enter "1" for example when choosing a row to delete, it deletes a row (in this case "1) Bob Jones, Comp, 18"). A row is made up of i + First Name + Surname + Course + Mark, all concatenated together.

Now, I have looked around the internet on code helping me do delete an entry. I have tried if i equals user input, then delete. I have tried using a temporary file where the user searches by first name (I am unsure how to code this though") and then writes back to original using BufferedWriter etc. I have been unsuccessful on making this work though.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ExamGrades {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        FileWriter grades = new FileWriter("grades2.txt",true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(grades);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int examMark = 0;
        String firstName = "";
        String surName = "";
        String course = "";
        String entry = "";
        String firstCap = "";
        String surCap = "";
        int menu =0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the 'GradeEnter' program! ");
        System.out.println("Menu: ");
        System.out.println("1) Enter Student Grade(s)");
        System.out.println("2) View Student Grade(s)");
        System.out.println("3) Delete Grade(s)");
        System.out.println("4) Exit");
        menu = scan.nextInt();

        switch (menu) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Please enter student first name: ");
            firstName = scan.next(); 

            while(!firstName.matches("[-a-zA-Z]*"))
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid first name: ");
                firstName = scan.next(); 
            }
            firstCap = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1);


            System.out.print("Please enter student surname: ");
            surName = scan.next();

            while(!surName.matches("[-a-zA-Z]*"))
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid surname: ");
                surName = scan.next();
            }
            surCap = surName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + surName.substring(1);

            System.out.print("Please select student course: "); 
            course = scan.next(); 

            System.out.print("Please enter student mark: ");
            while (!scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter a valid mark: ");
                scan.next();
            }
            examMark = scan.nextInt();

            if (examMark < 40)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }
            else if (examMark >= 40 && examMark <= 49)
            {
                System.out.println("3rd");
            }
            else if (examMark >= 50 && examMark <= 59)
            {
                System.out.println("2/2");
            }
            else if (examMark >= 60 && examMark <= 69)
            {
                System.out.println("2/1");
            }
            else if (examMark >= 70 && examMark <= 100)
            {
                System.out.println("1st");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Mark");
            }

            entry = (firstCap + " " + surCap + ", " + course + ", " + examMark);
            out.println(entry);
            break;

        case 2:
            File file = new File("grades2.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            int i =1;

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(i + ") " + line);    
                i++; 
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            // HERE
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Thanks for using 'GradeEnter' ");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        } 

        out.close();
        scan.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048633/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-with-java-using-scanner

Comment: Could you use a Database instead of a file? Would make this much easier

Comment: Read all of "grades2.txt" into a List before you ask the user for any information.  Add, change, and delete students from the List.  Write "grades2.txt" after the user selects option 4.  Also, break your monolithic code into methods.  A method should do one thing, and do it well.